# SQL Select Count/Distinct

Tags: sql-server, select, count, distinct

I have a big table with lots of data and I'm trying to find the best way of doing something that seems a bit tricky (to me, having my experience).

I have a table with data that looks like this...

```
Tbl1

IDClient             ApptDate            ApptType
788-77               7/1/2016            1
789-78               7/21/2016           1
688-12               7/15/2016           2
459-48               7/20/2016           1
788-77               7/2/2016            1
788-77               7/19/2016           2
789-78               7/29/2016           1
```

So as you can see here there are a few clients with ApptDate and ApptType <-- I'm including this column because it's used in my where criteria.

Here's my dilemna...

Client 788-77 has 3 appt's in July (july and appttype in (1,2) are my criteria, so all records in the provided table apply). Client 789-78 has 2 appt's. I'm trying to find a way to be able to display a DISTINCT IDClient, and how many appointments they've had between '7/1/2016' and '7/31/2016'

Desired End result:

```
IDClient         ApptCount
788-77           3
789-78           2
459-48           1
688-12           1
```

Something like this....( I know I'm butchering this)

```
Select Distinct IDClient, Count(IdClient)?
from Tbl1 
where apptType in (1,2) and apptDate between '7/1/2016' and '7/31/2016'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try this `group by`?

```
Select IDClient, Count(IdClient) 
from Tbl1 
where apptType in (1,2) and apptDate between '7/1/2016' and '7/31/2016'
group by IDClient
```

Comment: That did it, i was close!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT IDClient, COUNT(IDClient) AS ApptCount
FROM Tbl1
WHERE ApptDate BETWEEN '1996-07-01' AND '1996-07-31'
GROUP BY IDClient
```

Comment: what if i want to display only clients with 3 appts?

Comment: Sorry I missed that! You could add a having clause HAVING COUNT(IDClient) = 3